# If $f = u +iv$ is differentiable, then how to prove that its components $u$ and $v$ are differentiable?

Tags: complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

I know that there is a sufficient condition theorem which states that that the partial derivatives have to continuous and $f$ should satisfy CR equation. But how to prove the opposite of the statement? ($f $ is differentiable  $\implies $ continuity of partial derivatives)

Comment: $f\in H(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C} $ open.

Then, then the partial derivatives $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y $ of $f=u+ iv$ exists and satisfy C-R equations. And 

$$f'(z) =u_x +i\space  v_x$$

Since, $f\in H(\Omega)$ , $f'$ is also Holomorphic on $ \Omega$.(why?) 

And then $ f' $ is continuous. 

We know , $f'=(u_x , v_x) $ continuous iff continuous co-ordinate wise. 

$u_x , v_x $ are continuous and continuity of other partial derivatives follows from C-R equations. 

In fact, $f$ is smooth on $\Omega$ ,derivatives of all order exists and continuous.

Comment: I haven't learnt holomorphic functions. Could you explain why f' is continuous